# insert key/value pair into an array with two level

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in my project:

```
$my_array(
array(
    'a' => 'value1',
    'b' => 'value2',
    'c' => 'value3',
),
array(
    'a' => 'value4',
    'b' => 'value5',
    'c' => 'value6',
),
);
```

I want to add a key/value pair into all of arrays (after all 'c' keys ) without looping structure, like this :

```
$my_array(
array(
    'a' => 'value1',
    'b' => 'value2',
    'c' => 'value3',
    'MyInsertedKey' => 'MyInsertedValue'
),
array(
    'a' => 'value4',
    'b' => 'value5',
    'c' => 'value6',
    'MyInsertedKey' => 'MyInsertedValue'        

),
);
```

please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it for all elements, you can:

```
$extended = array_map(function ($e) {
    $e['EXTENDED'] = 'hi';
    return $e;
}, $my_array);
```